# Include first two characters after split in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have two columns in my dataset that both contain two concatenated prices, which looks like this:

```
189.00141.75
99.9974.99
10.498.61
```

I want the first column to look like this:

```
189.00
99.99
10.49
```

And the second column to look like this:

```
141.75
74.99
8.61
```

Basically what I want is to split each line after the first dot (.), but to include the first two characters after the split. How do I do that?

I tried with the split() method but I couldn't manage to get the right output.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `findall` with 2 capture groups:

```
>>> s = '189.00141.75'
>>> re.findall(r'^(\d+\.\d{2})(\d+\.\d{2})', s)
[('189.00', '141.75')]
```

Here:

- `^(\d+\.\d{2})`: is capture group #1 that matches 1+ digits followed by a dot followed by 2 digits
- `(\d+\.\d{2})`: is capture group #2 that matches 1+ digits followed by a dot followed by 2 digits

Comment: Why not just repeat the same capture group twice, instead of matching everything else on the line? Wouldn't it be safer?

Comment: @AMC: Yes sure `^(\d+\.\d{2})(\d+\.\d{2})` can be used. (Edited) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could do :

```
string = "189.00141.75"
num1, num2 = string[0:string.index('.')+3], string[string.index('.')+3:]
print(num1, num2)
```

Output

```
('189.00', '141.75')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a simple [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to add a space (or any other delimiter) between the fields, and then continue your processing:

```
for line in get_lines_of_dataset_from_whereever():

    line = re.sub(r'(\.\d\d)', r'\1 ', line, count=1)  # change count, if needed

    do_other_stuff_with(line)
```